# parse into database from javascript form

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a webpage with form which is processed with javascript code. There is a form with button with javascript `onClick()` method.
Here is the webpage ([czech declensions](http://pteryx.net/sklonovani.html))

On input I have a list of names in mysql database. I need to put a single name form list into a form, click on button to invoke `onClick()` method and on output I want to have name with declension (field 5. vokativ in form) - insert it into database table. This action in cycle for each name from a list form database.

Please, any suggestions how can be this done?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ajax to do this trick..

With jQuery it could be done pretty easy if I understand you right.

It could look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "validate.php?info=something&otherinfo=somethingelse"
}).done(function() {
  alert('done');
});
```

You could get all the informations by doing this:

```
var something = $('input[name=something]').val();
```

Then make the PHP page handle the informations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a problem because I don´t have a url in a form of "...php?info=abcd"

Comment: But you can make that, as a PHP script. Then it will get everything after the `?` as varialbes. Like `validate.php?message=hej&name=Petr`, then you could handle it on validate.php the following way: `echo "$_GET['message'] $_GET['name']"`, it would return `hej Petr`. Else if you don't want to use aJax, you could use node.js, but it requires some additional installs to your host.